# Hierarchical dependency injection in angular4

Tags: angular

I have a hierarchy as follows.

```
Component1
    Component2
        component3
```

This hierarchy can be used or user may use component2 or component3 individually.
Each component will be injected with AggregatorService.

I want to inject the aggregation service such that it should check if parent exists,it should use that service instance instead of creating new instance.

If its used individually, it should get the new instance of the service.

I know it works if we want the preference to the closest injection.

But How can I achieve this one?

Comment: What do you mean with "component will be injected". Components normally are not injected. What is "aggregation service"? Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: No component is not injected. I meant each component will have same service injected in the constructor.
Actually you have understood my requirement. Let me try your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Optional()`

```ts
constructor(@Optional() private service?:AggregatorService) {
  if(!this.service) {
    this.service = new AggregatorService();
  }
}
```

or to avoid creating an instance with `new`

```ts
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  providers: [{provide: 'myAggService', useClass: AggregatorService}],
})
constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() private service?:AggregatorService, @Inject('myAggService') myAggService:AggregatorService) {
  if(!this.service) {
    this.service = myAggService;
  }
}
```

a small disadvantage is, that here always an own instances is created,
but then dropped if one from the parent is received.

Comment: But if I use the <Component1></Component1> in this case, it will create separate object in Component3 right? In Component3, I want the service instance which was created in Component1 in this case. Please confirm.

Comment: Please answer my questions in the comment below your questions first, otherwise I can't be sure what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: My approach is, that if a parent scope provides a service, this one is used, if not, then a new instance for this component is created.